# Condicionante en variable numérica para aplicar otra condicionante de clasificación

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo que evaluar algunos parámetros de suelo, pero algunos dependen de otro para interpretarlos, asi que aplicar una condición no es correcto ya que existe una que debe cumplirse antes. mi ejemplo:

la cuantificacion del fósforo en laboratorio utiliza dos técnicas, Olsen y Bray cuando el pH es mayor 7 y menor respectivamente, ademas cada uno tiene sus rangos de referencia:

```
Int <- function(x, element='element'){
if(element=='P_Ols'){Niv <-  ifelse(x <= 5.5, yes = "bajo",
                                     no =ifelse(x >= 11, yes= "alto", 
                                                ifelse( x < 11 & x > 5.5, "Medio", "FR")))}
if(element=='P_Bry'){Niv <-  ifelse(x <= 15, yes = "bajo",
                                      no =ifelse(x >= 30, yes= "alto", 
                                                 ifelse( x < 30 & x > 15, "Medio", "FR")))}
 return(Niv)
}
```

se que especificar el ultimo rango es innecesario ya que es el intervalo que define seria el resto de los datos y he colocado FR=fuera de rango que también lo es porque mis intervalos no excluyen negativos o valores demasiado altos pero en fin posiblemente despues agrege otro limite para valores atipicos/erroneos y ocupe esa parte

y la aplico asi:

```
   DF$PI <- Int(DF$P..mg.kg.1, 'P_Bry') # o ya sea 'P_Ols'
```

esto funciona muy bien pero tengo métodos mezclados y muchos datos,  por lo tanto parto el df antes:

```
DF2 <- DF2[DF2$pH > 7, ]
DF3 <- DF2[DF2$pH < 7, ]
```

y hacerlo individualmente

```
DF3$PI <- Int(DF3$P..mg.kg.1, 'P_Bry') 
DF2$PI <- Int(DF2$P..mg.kg.1, 'P_Ols')
```

y después unirlo nuevamente

```
 DF<- rbind(DF2, DF3)
```

por cierto, una parte de los datos para probar:

```
DF <- structure(list(pH = c(6.95, 7.35, 6.5, 7.06, 7.25, 7.03, 7.59, 
8.32, 6.24, 7.07), P..mg.kg.1. = c(14.94, 4.23, 9.46, 12.45, 
4.48, 19.67, 6.47, 8.96, 11.2, 8.71), ID_UACh = c(393L, 398L, 
399L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 406L, 407L, 409L, 410L)), row.names = c(11L, 
16L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L), class = "data.frame")
```

existe la forma de evaluar esto dentro de la función para no tener que partir el df y volver a juntarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, puedes aplicar la función a selecciones parciales de los datos:

```
DF$PI[DF$pH < 7] <- Int(DF$P..mg.kg.1[DF$pH < 7], 'P_Bry') 
DF$PI[DF$pH > 7] <- Int(DF$P..mg.kg.1[DF$pH > 7], 'P_Ols')
```

También podrías reformular la función, para que el `pH` participe en el calculo:

```
Int <- function(x, y){
  P_Ols <- as.character(cut(x, c(-Inf, 5.5, 11, Inf), labels=c('bajo', 'medio', 'alto')))
  P_Bry <- as.character(cut(x, c(-Inf, 15, 30, Inf), labels=c('bajo', 'medio', 'alto')))

  ifelse(y > 7, P_Ols, P_Bry)
}
```

Nota: Cuando tienes que categorizar rangos, la función `cut()` es maravillosa por que simplifica enormemente la lógica y es mucho más comprensible.

Ejemplo:

```
DF$PI <-  Int(DF$P..mg.kg.1, DF$pH) 
DF

     pH P..mg.kg.1. ID_UACh    PI
11 6.95       14.94     393  bajo
16 7.35        4.23     398  bajo
17 6.50        9.46     399  bajo
20 7.06       12.45     402  alto
21 7.25        4.48     403  bajo
22 7.03       19.67     404  alto
24 7.59        6.47     406 medio
25 8.32        8.96     407 medio
27 6.24       11.20     409  bajo
28 7.07        8.71     410 medio
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes crear una función con dos argumentos:

```
ph_fun <- function(x,y){
  Niv = 'FR'
  if(y > 7){
    if(x <= 5.5){
      Niv = 'bajo'
    }
    if(x >= 11){
      Niv = 'alto'
    }
    if(x < 11 & x > 5.5){
      Niv = 'medio'
    }
  }
  if(y < 7){
    if(x <= 15){
      Niv = 'bajo'
    }
    if(x >= 30){
      Niv = 'alto'
    }
    if(x < 30 & x > 15){
      Niv = 'medio'
    }
  }
  Niv
}
```

Y luego aplicarla con `mapply`:

```
DF$Niv <- mapply(ph_fun,DF$P..mg.kg.1., DF$pH)         
DF
#      pH P..mg.kg.1. ID_UACh   Niv
# 11 6.95       14.94     393  bajo
# 16 7.35        4.23     398  bajo
# 17 6.50        9.46     399  bajo
# 20 7.06       12.45     402  alto
# 21 7.25        4.48     403  bajo
# 22 7.03       19.67     404  alto
# 24 7.59        6.47     406 medio
# 25 8.32        8.96     407 medio
# 27 6.24       11.20     409  bajo
# 28 7.07        8.71     410 medio
```

Establecer 'FR' al principio de la funcion te permite omitir asignar este valor más adelante con nuevos `if`.